# Error using sed command to replace references to include file that has changed name

Tags: sed, grep, xargs

I've renamed an include file and I'd like to replace all references to it in my code, all files are in the same directory.

After researching several websites, I keep getting errors when I try the following (however it seems to work for others, maybe because I'm using Mac OS X)

```
grep -rl 'old-file.php' . | xargs sed -i 's/old-file.php/new-file.php/g'
```

I seem to get an error relating to the first grep matched file:

> sed: 1: "./somefile.php": invalid command code .

I've tried various forms of escaping the . ([.] and .) neither seem to work.

Any helpful suggestions are most welcome!

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -rl 'old-file.php' . | xargs sed -i 's#old-file.php#new-file.php#g'
```

use other separator  than `/` in this sed (or escape the `/`)

now if the ./someFile is in the nsearch pattern (old-file) use maybe `[.]` or `\.` in this part of the sed. to avoid other matching value like  `(ba)d/old_file.php`

Comment: Seems to be regarding use of 'sed -i'. I have to put 'sed -i ""'. I can't leave it blank like in examples I have seen

Comment: @SimonBosley - yes, `-i` is only available in some `sed`s and even when available whether or not it requires an argument is dependent on the version of `sed` you are using.